# PowerShell Variable IF Statement from windows form

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to so write a PowerShell script that performs a task based on the input from a windows form.

```
If ($ComboBoxOffice.Text -eq 'Norwich', $CheckBoxNoEquipment.Checked -eq 'False' )
```

I can get it to work with just the following code:

```
If ($ComboBoxOffice.Text -eq 'Norwich')
```

Any ideas on how would go about only actioning the IF statement based on the input from the first code?

Comment: Are you looking for `-and` condition? See if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.1) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to proceed when BOTH conditions are satisfied, use the `-and` operator:

```
if($ComboBoxOffice.Text -eq 'Norwich' -and $CheckBoxNoEquipment.Checked -eq $false){
    # ...
}
```

If you want to proceed when *either* condition is satisfied, use `-or`:

```
if($ComboBoxOffice.Text -eq 'Norwich' -or $CheckBoxNoEquipment.Checked -eq $false){
    # ...
}
```

Notice that I'm using the special boolean variable `$false` rather than the string `'False'`, to [avoid type confusion bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345334/why-does-true-equal-true/37345480#37345480)