# if statement in power-shell choose 'wrong' option

Tags: powershell

I have a list of servers to which I should have access. I know that to some of them I have not. I want to check access to each server and list only that ones to which I do not have access. To do that I created script which for each server use `test-netconnection` function to check if I am able to connect and then I use `if` statement to write server name to the file if the test was not successful.  Unfortunately seems that `if` does not work as I expected.

Could you please advice what I am doing wrong with the example below?

I run the below script

```
$test_result.TcpTestSucceeded


   if($test_result.TcpTestSucceeded -eq 'False' )
    {
        Write-Output 'a'
    }
    else
        {
        Write-Output 'b'
    }
```

and I have the below result

[image]

As you can see even-though value is `true` powershell choose option `a`, while I would expect that option `b` should be displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does 'true' equal $true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345334/why-does-true-equal-true) which also explains opposite: why **`$true` *not* equals `'true'`** (or **`$false` *not* equals `'false'`**).

Answer (score 1):

$test_result.TcpTestSucceeded

if($test_result.TcpTestSucceeded -eq $False )
{
Write-Output 'a'
}
else
{
Write-Output 'b'
}

Try This

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.