# Powershell switch statement comparison value 1d erractic, why?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

```
$UserChoice = Read-Host "Enter # of tool you want to run"
switch -exact ($UserChoice) {
    1 {Write-Host 'You selected 1'}
    1a {Write-Host 'You selected 1a'}
    1b {Write-Host 'You selected 1b'}
    1c {Write-Host 'You selected 1c'}
    1d {Write-Host 'You selected 1d'}
}
```

Preface: I know the fix is to put the comparison values in quotes, ex: `'1d'`. **I want to know WHY PowerShell is acting the way it is for learning sake.**

1. If I enter 1b at prompt, it returns 1b whereas if I enter 1d it returns nothing, why?
2. If I enter 1b at prompt, it returns 1b whereas if I enter 1 it returns 1 and 1d, why?
3. It seems PowerShell is interpreting d in a switch statement comparison value different for some reason, why?

I noticed VISUALLY the comparison values are different colors (1 & 1d are darker) so I guess PowerShell ISE syntax highlighting is telling us they're being treated differently. 4. What do the colors mean (maroon/dark-RedOrPurple VS purple?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before explaining why the `1d` label is "special", I should note that the `-exact` mode (which is the default mode of comparison for a `switch` statement) is probably a bit misleading.

It simply means "use the `-eq` operator to compare input values to case labels".

The reason `1d` behaves differently is that *PowerShell doesn't recognize the expression `1d` as a string*. Instead, it interprets `d` is a numerical suffix signifying the `[decimal]` type, and the case label value is thus the same as if you'd written `1.0` or `$([decimal]1)`.

The result is that comparison to the input string `"1"` comes out the same for both - `"1" -eq 1` and `"1" -eq 1d` are both true, thanks to PowerShell's [overloaded operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345334/why-does-true-equal-true/37345480#37345480).

If you ever expand your options further, you'll encounter the same problem with `1l` (`l` = `[long]`), and, if using PowerShell 7, eventually `1n`, `1s`, `1u`, and `1y`.

Quote the switch labels to avoid PowerShell parsing them as a numerical expressions:

```
$UserChoice = Read-Host "Enter # of tool you want to run"
switch -exact ($UserChoice) {
    '1'  {Write-Host 'You selected 1'}
    '1a' {Write-Host 'You selected 1a'}
    '1b' {Write-Host 'You selected 1b'}
    '1c' {Write-Host 'You selected 1c'}
    '1d' {Write-Host 'You selected 1d'}
}
```

See the [about_Numeric_Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.2) help topic for a more comprehensive overview of suffixes interpreted as numerical modfiers by PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks so I guess `d` is telling PowerShell to change the datatype thus changing its value so won't match, got it. I updated my question with a picture showing the colors being different, can you explain what the colors mean (question 4)? Guessing PowerShell ISE syntax highlighting is trying to tell me ones a string vs decimal. Question 5)why doesn't the $UserChoice variable datatype change when you enter 1d (aka why is switch comparison value affected & an undefined variable datatype isn't)?

Comment: @gregg That's exactly right! PowerShell's parser first tries to see if the case label is a constant, variable or pipeline expression (like `1d`, or `$true`, or `$('1' + 'c')` for example), but if it encounters a bare word that _isn't_ one of those (for example `1b` or `hello` or `gregg`) it then falls back to interpreting it as a string literal, the same as if you'd written `"1b"` instead of just `1b`. The color differences you see in ISE shows _exactly that_ - unlike the other three labels, `1d` is colored the same as any other numerical constant.

Comment: These cmdlets help see it as well: `(1).GetType()`; `(1d).GetType()`; `(1b).GetType()`. So while `switch` is simple the powershell logic/parsing complicates it. Since you work at MS thought I'd point out their guide examples ALSO don't put quotes on most switch labels: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-switch?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @gregg I don't work at MS, but the documentation is open for public revision and feedback, simply click through the links at the bottom of the page (where it says "Submit and view feedback for ...") if you think the examples could be better :)

Comment: Darn, I was hoping this might solve my problem, which is a `"N3"` case (including being double-quoted) being skipped. Do you think it's a similar reason as the reason in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Mathias' excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683051/45375):

- The [`switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683051/45375) statement's branch conditionals should never have allowed the use of *barewords* (*unquoted* tokens serving as *strings*).

  - It amounts to an inappropriate blending of PowerShell's two fundamental [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), *argument mode* and *expression mode*.

    - In expression mode - which is the appropriate one to apply - strings *must* be quoted; e.g., to match a *string* with verbatim value `1d`, it must be represented as `'1d'`, which disambiguates it from the *number literal* `1d`, a `[decimal]`.
  - See [GitHub issue #3668](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3668) for a discussion.
- The `-exact` switch opts into the *default* behavior and, given the *non-exact* nature of this behavior, is *confusingly named*.

  - [GitHub issue #8599](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8599) therefore suggests (soft-)*deprecating* it.